# How to handle lists as single values in csv with Python

Tags: python, regex, list, csv

I am handling a csv import and got troubles with a value that should be in list form but is read as string.

One of the csv rows looks like the following:

```
    ['name1', "['name2', 'name3']"]
```

As you can see the value in the second column is a list but is read as a string. My problem is that I need to iterate through that list and the length of that list can vary from row to row.

I am wondering where the problem lies. Can csv read not handle a list? Is there a way to turn that string in the second column into a list rather than using regex?
Here is the code that I am running:

```
    import csv
    import os

    content = []
    file_path = os.path.abspath(file)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
      with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
      for row in csvreader:
        content.append(row)
      for row in content[1:5]:
        print row
      print row[0], row[1]
      for name in row[1]:
        print name
```

The output row looks as above but when iterating though row[1] it does not iterate though the list of names but through every single character. Anyone got an idea?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No, the csv module cannot turn a string into a list, can you add a sample of what your input looks like? How did you end up with a list written to the file?

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham for quick answer. In a different application it made sense to save multiple string values in one cell to csv. Rows look like in the first example ['name1', "['name2', 'name3']"]. Probably there is a better way to handle this?

Comment: why is the structure `['name1', "['name2', 'name3']"].`? How do you end up with nested lists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'll give some more context. csv shows interactions between different users. So full line looks the following: `[date, text, id, 'name1', "['name2', 'name3']"]` meaning that user1 mentions both user2 and user3. At time of creating csv it seemed like most convenient solution

Comment: I think maybe storing dicts or maybe use pandas would be a good idea, what are you doing with the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82688/discussion-between-justus-niemzok-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to convert string to list is using `ast.literal_eval` function.

Example -

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['name2', 'name3']"
>>> s
"['name2', 'name3']"
>>> l = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> l
['name2', 'name3']
>>> type(l)
<class 'list'>
```

From ast [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) -

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

But if your complete csv looks like that, you should consider using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse the csv, rather than `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your second list item is a valid python data type, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("['name2', 'name3']")
['name2', 'name3']
```

So in your particular case,you may want to do the following

```
  .............
  row[1] = ast.literal_eval(row[1])
  print row[0], row[1]
  for name in row[1]:
    print name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using `literal_eval` to convert string to corresponding `class`

```
from ast import literal_eval
for name in literal_eval(row[1]):
   print name
```

or

```
for name in eval(row[1]):
   print name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=['name1', "['name2', 'name3']"]
import re
print [ast.literal_eval(i) if re.match(r"\[.*?\]",i) else i for i in x ]
```

OUTPUT: `['name1', ['name2', 'name3']]`

You can use `ast.literal_eval` and `re` to convert string in list to list and leave others as they are.